# Java FileExeptions throw not found but file really exist

Tags: java, file, maven, filenotfoundexception

I have method for reading from file:

```
public String getFile(String fileName) {
    String line;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    try {
        //Get file from resources folder
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"))) {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Err: " + e);
    }

    return (result.toString());
}
```

When I run this code I am getting a exeption `java.io.FileNotFoundException`
:

> Err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Programov%C3%A1n%C3%AD\GITBitBucket\Quick%20Annotation\maven-project-quickannotation\target\classes\template\basic.txt

But I am sure, that file really exist.

Original path is:

> D:\Programování\GITBitBucket\Quick
>   Annotation\maven-project-quickannotation\target\classes\template\basic.txt

I think, there is a problem with section of path:

```
Programov%C3%A1n%C3%AD vs Programování

Quick%20Annotation vs Quick Annotation
```

Can you help me?

I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My guess is, the problem is not within the method you posted but in the code calling your `getFile(String)` method. Because the `String fileName` contains encoded special characters. Where does that value come from?  -- [Debug your application](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I am caling the method using this code: getFile("template/basic.txt");

Comment: My bad. `Classloader.getResource(String name)` returns an `URL` that's the reason.

Comment: URL.getFile() **does not** return a valid file name, even for `file:` URLs.  It returns the path and query portions of the URL.  The method was part of Java 1.0, and its name made sense back when most URLs actually referred to actual local or remote files.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

to retrieve an `InputStream` directly instead of the detour over `File`.

see [Oracle ClassLoader API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Answer (score -1):

You need to call with the path, but not using "classLoader.getResource", as this gets resources inside the jar.

try:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
```

This way you are looking for a file using a system path.

Comment: Nope, I need build path using classloader in my spring application.